# Erro ao importar CSV para o phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, microsoft-excel, phpmyadmin, banco-de-dados, csv

Eu preciso de importar um ficheiro `.csv` para o phpMyAdmin, mas os caracteres especiais não aparecem, nem o texto que os segue. Qual pode ser o problema?

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: O seu arquivo está em UTF-8 ou em ANSI? Tente abrir no [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) e conferir o formato do arquivo e se for o caso converter para UTF-8

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: Vou escrever esta solução como resposta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Explicação do problema

Normalmente arquivos de texto com caracteres especiais precisam ser salvos em [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8), da mesma forma os bancos de dados que guardam textos que também possuem caracteres especiais devem ser salvos no mesmo formato.

Desta forma presumo que seu arquivo de texto está no formato [ansi](/questions/tagged/ansi), onde o UTF-8 compreende perfeitamente todos os caracteres contemplados pelo ANSI, porém o contrário não acontece.

Portanto sempre que você tenta ler caracteres especiais e um arquivo de texto no formato ANSI usando UTF-8 ele dá erro exatamente no local onde estão os caracteres especiais e o arquivo para de ser lido.

Por este motivo o phpMyAdmin não executa a importação completamente.

### Solução

Converta o tipo do arquivo para UTF-8 (recomendo usar o [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) e em seguida realize a importação normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Para importar corretamente um arquivo CSV, os campos de auto increment (tipo id) devem estar vazios. Para isso, salve sua planilha do excel no formato csv, deixando o campo de os respectivos campos de ID vazios. Em seguida, abra o arquivo criado em excel pelo notepad.exe e salve novamente o arquivo só que agora com a codificação uft-8. Depois vá ao phpmyadmin e importe o arquivo criado no notepad.exe. Observe marcar a caixa para alterar a primeira linha (onde contém os títulos das colunas), também substitua as caixas com a vírgula (,) por (;) e exclua as aspas (") das respectivas opções.

Answer (score -2):

Caso o problema persista mesmo após a conversão, pode tentar informar a ordem das colunas no campo com o respectivo nome. Conforme a imagem:

[image: Mostra o campo nome das colunas que deve ser informado]